# Insert url for if else in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have written a code in template, if a parent is logged in and have invites then he can view a child link.

```
              {%  if cwistprofile.is_parent and cwistprofile.invites > 0 %}
                <div id="kid_login"><a id="kid_login_image" href="#kids_profile"></a></div>
                {% include 'child/child_link.html' %}
               {%  endif %}
```

Now I want to add an extra if condition that do not open the child link if certain url is open? How do I implement this?

URL code:

```
           urls.url(r'^contact$', views.Contact.as_view(), name='contact')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access HttpRequest object inside your template and test the path.

First ensure that `'django.core.context_processors.request'` is inside `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` inside `settings.py`. It should look something like this.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

And then inside your template you can use it like this:

```
{% if request.path == '/contact/' %}
    do something here
{% endif %}
```

Check the django docs for full list of goodsies you get from HttpRequest object:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest